# Gitlab - Postgresql not working anymore after gitlabctl-reconfigure

Tags: debian, postgresql, gitlab

I just installed a brand new server with Gitlab.
The first time I done gitlab-ctl reconfigure it worked like a charm.

After that, I didn't change anything but ran gitlab-ctl reconfigure again.
This is where problems started, I see many failed attempts to connect to pgsql.

```
[execute] psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
            Is the server running locally and accepting
            connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

So i tried gitlab-ctl stop and gitlab-ctl start which says it started postgresql.

```
ok: run: postgresql: (pid 11766) 0s
```

How can I do to fix this ? 
I end up with a 502 error... "Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond."

Regards,

I am lost, it's a jessie plain install with only gitlab and nagios, munin, rsync.

Answer (score 0):

I changed kernel.shmmax to 1024Mb and it now works.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1405 -> same issue

Answer (score 0):

edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

then enable this setting

```
postgresql['shared_buffers'] = "512MB" # recommend value is 1/4 of total RAM, up to 14GB.
```